# Creating an employee manager relationship table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've a table as under:

**Original table**:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Employee Name | Manager Lvl1 | Manager Lvl2 |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| A             | L            | Y            |
| B             | M            | Y            |
| C             | L            | Y            |
| D             | M            | Y            |
| E             | N            | Z            |
| F             | N            | Z            |
| G             | O            | Z            |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to add an id to all employee levels and also a column that specifies the manager ID for each employee as under:

**Desired Employee Table**:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| ID | Employee | Manager ID |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | A        |          8 |
|  2 | B        |          9 |
|  3 | C        |          8 |
|  4 | D        |          9 |
|  5 | E        |         10 |
|  6 | F        |         10 |
|  7 | G        |         11 |
|  8 | L        |         12 |
|  9 | M        |         12 |
| 10 | N        |         13 |
| 11 | O        |         13 |
| 12 | Y        |            |
| 13 | Z        |            |
+----+----------+------------+
```

My main aim in doing this is to add a path column to create a path of each employee manager relation so that I can add row level security:

The path function that I'd be using is:

```
EmployeePath= Employee[ID], Employee[Manager ID])
```

so that my end table would look like this:

```
+----+----------+------------+---------+
| ID | Employee | Manager ID |  Path   |
+----+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 | A        |          8 | 12|8|1  |
|  2 | B        |          9 | 12|8|2  |
|  3 | C        |          8 | 12|8|3  |
|  4 | D        |          9 | 12|9|4  |
|  5 | E        |         10 | 13|10|5 |
|  6 | F        |         10 | 13|10|6 |
|  7 | G        |         11 | 13|11|7 |
|  8 | L        |         12 | 12|8    |
|  9 | M        |         12 | 12|9    |
| 10 | N        |         13 | 13|10   |
| 11 | O        |         13 | 13|11   |
| 12 | Y        |            | 12      |
| 13 | Z        |            | 13      |
+----+----------+------------+---------+
```

I'm just having a hard time converting my **oiginal table** to the format of the **desired employee** table

Comment: Do you have more Manager level? or up to level 2?

Comment: @R_R I've upto level 3

Comment: Do your employee names are unique in all columns?

Comment: @R_R  No, they are not, they’re repeated multiple times

Comment: Repeated is fine, but is all M is a same person?

Comment: @R_R yes, all the employees with have just one immediate and the same manager; I hope that answers the question, so all M’s would be same person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform some transformation in **Power Query Editor** to achieve the required output. Lets say your table name is **Employee** with this below structure-

[image]

Now, the transformation is bit long, but try to understand step by step. If you can understand, things will be easy. Duplicate your table **Employee** and replace with the below code from **Advance Editor**-

```
let
    Source = employee,
        
    L0 =    
    Table.Distinct(         
        Table.FromList(
            Table.Column(Source,"Employee Name"),
            Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error
        )
    ),
    
    L1 =    
    Table.Distinct(         
        Table.FromList(
            Table.Column(Source,"Manager Lvl1"),
            Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error
        )                
    ),
    
    L2 =
    Table.Distinct(       
        Table.FromList(
            Table.Column(Source,"Manager Lvl2"),
            Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error
        )
    ),
    
    L3 =
    Table.Distinct(         
        Table.FromList(
            Table.Column(Source,"Manager Lvl3"),
            Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error
        )
    ),

    
    combine_table = 
    Table.Combine({
        L0,L1,L2,L3
    }),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(combine_table, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Column1"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns", {"Column1"}, employee, {"Employee Name"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "employee", {"Manager Lvl1"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl1"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded employee", {"Column1"}, employee, {"Manager Lvl1"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "employee", {"Manager Lvl2"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl2"}),
    #"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded employee1", {"Column1"}, employee, {"Manager Lvl2"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "employee", {"Manager Lvl3"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl3"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Expanded employee2",{"employee.Manager Lvl1", "employee.Manager Lvl2", "employee.Manager Lvl3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Merged Columns"),
    #"Merged Queries3" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Merged"}, employee, {"Manager Lvl1"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries3", "employee", {"Manager Lvl2"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl2"}),
    #"Merged Queries4" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded employee3", {"Merged"}, employee, {"Manager Lvl2"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee4" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries4", "employee", {"Manager Lvl3"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl3"}),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Expanded employee4",{"employee.Manager Lvl2", "employee.Manager Lvl3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Removed Duplicates1" = Table.Distinct(#"Merged Columns1"),
    #"Merged Queries5" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Duplicates1", {"Merged.1"}, employee, {"Manager Lvl2"}, "employee", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded employee5" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries5", "employee", {"Manager Lvl3"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl3"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates2" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded employee5"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Duplicates2",{{"Merged", "M1"}, {"Merged.1", "M2"}, {"employee.Manager Lvl3", "M3"}}),
    #"Merged Queries6" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns", {"M1"}, #"Renamed Columns", {"Column1"}, "Renamed Columns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries6", "Renamed Columns", {"Index"}, {"Renamed Columns.Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns",{{"Renamed Columns.Index", "M1_ID"}}),
    #"Merged Queries7" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns1", {"M2"}, #"Renamed Columns1", {"Column1"}, "Renamed Columns1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries7", "Renamed Columns1", {"Index"}, {"Renamed Columns1.Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns1",{{"Renamed Columns1.Index", "M2_ID"}}),
    #"Merged Queries8" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns2", {"M3"}, #"Renamed Columns2", {"Column1"}, "Renamed Columns2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries8", "Renamed Columns2", {"Index"}, {"Renamed Columns2.Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns2",{{"Renamed Columns2.Index", "M3_ID"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns3",{"Index", "Column1", "M1", "M1_ID", "M2", "M2_ID", "M3", "M3_ID"}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Reordered Columns1", "Index", "Index - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Index - Copy", "M0_ID"}}),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns4", "M1_ID", "M1_ID - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns5" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column1",{{"M1_ID - Copy", "Manager ID"}}),
    #"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns5", {{"M1_ID", type text}, {"M2_ID", type text}, {"M3_ID", type text}, {"M0_ID", type text}}, "en-US"),{"M1_ID", "M2_ID", "M3_ID", "M0_ID"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns2","||","|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Merged"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","||","|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Merged"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value1",{"M2", "M3", "M1"}),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Index", "Column1", "Manager ID", "Merged"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns2"
```

Here is the final output of your new table-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit shorter, requires just a few self merges

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Manager ID"},Source,{"ID"},"Changed Type",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Changed Type", {"Manager ID"}, {"Manager ID.1"}),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Changed Type",{"Manager ID.1"},#"Expanded Changed Type",{"ID"},"Expanded Changed Type",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Expanded Changed Type", {"Manager ID"}, {"Manager ID.2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Expanded Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Manager ID.2]=null then 

if  [Manager ID] = null then Text.From([ID]) else if
[Manager ID.1] = null then Text.From([Manager ID])&" | "&Text.From([ID])
else Text.From([Manager ID.1])&" | " &Text.From([Manager ID])&" | "&Text.From([ID])
else Text.From([Manager ID.2]) & "|" & Text.From([Manager ID.1]) & " | " & Text.From([Manager ID]) & " | " & Text.From([ID])),

#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})
in #"Sorted Rows"
```